# Chapter formatting - Move title to correct position

Tags: formatting, thesis, alignment

I have setup the following chapter formatting for my thesis:

```
% Selected packages from my pre-amble.
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Chapter format
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\bfseries} 
   {\filleft\hspace*{-60pt}
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
      \normalfont\color{black}\Large%
      \textls[90]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}%
   }\hspace{10pt}%
   {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
      \colorbox{myblue}{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{2.5cm}{%
      \centering\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont\thechapter}%
   }}
   }
   {10pt}
   {\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\huge}
```

Which yields the following result:

[image]

However, I want the chapter title to be moved upwards as depicted below:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/zdlbA]

I would appreciate any contribution which would enable me to accomplish the above task!

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a compilable minimal working example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. Note the `block` style is better for that. Next, you should add the horizontal rules as the `optional` argument of `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Chapter format
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
   {\rlap{\makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
      \normalfont\color{black}\Large%
      \textls[90]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}%
   }\hspace{10pt}%
   {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
      \colorbox{myblue}{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{2.5cm}{%
      \centering\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont\thechapter}%
   }}}%
   }}
   {0pt}
   {\huge\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-4cm}}[{\medskip\titlerule[2.5pt]}\vskip3pt\titlerule]
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Serious Title. Serious Title. Serious Title. Serious Title. Serious Title.}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]